# Delete temp files options for clearing the log files

Tags: 12.04

how to delete the temp file and cache files in ubuntu?
where as in windows o/s we have cmd prompt to view the %temp% cmd to delete it?
so kindly make the which cmd to use this option

Answer (score 0):

To cleanup the cache through terminal,you can use the following command

sudo apt-get autoclean - This command would cleanup the partial package so that there would be enough space left

sudo apt-get clean - This command  would Clean up of the apt cache